# Can double checked locking be abstracted/simplified?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

My company uses double checked locking all over the place in our code. Because it is so pervasive - and so verbose - I was wondering if there is a good way to abstract it or simplify it.

For example, would a utility method like this have any problems?

```
    public static <T> T doubleCheckedLocking(Object lockObject, Supplier<Boolean> check, Supplier<T> task, Supplier<T> defaultValueSupplier) {
        if (check.get())
            synchronized (lockObject) {
                if (check.get())
                    return task.get();
            }
        return defaultValueSupplier.get();
    }
```

With that it should be possible to convert common code like:

```
class MySingleton {
    static volatile MySingleton instance;

    private MySingleton() { /*...*/ }

    static MySingleton instance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (MySingleton.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new MySingleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

to:

```
class MySingleton {
    static volatile MySingleton instance;

    private MySingleton() { /*...*/ }

    static MySingleton instance() {
        return doubleCheckedLocking(MySingleton.class, () -> instance == null, () -> {
            instance = new MySingleton();
            return instance;
        }, () -> instance);
    }
}
```

Are there any problems with this approach? Are there any libraries or alternatives that might do this already?

Comment: In most cases, DCL can be simplified by removing the need to apply it, such as by using dependency injection or the enum singleton pattern. What purpose(s) is it serving in your code?

Comment: It's used fairly frequently in a variety of cases.  I agree that there are some options for singleton lazy initialization.  But we also use it for modifying object state - or affecting behavior with alternative logic like: if state == X, setState(Y) and return "foo", else return "bar".

Comment: Why do you think it might have a problem?

Comment: I haven’t seen patterns (or anti-patterns) like this when googling, so I was thinking that maybe there was some drawback to it - like maybe it really isn’t thread safe or it performs worse, etc.

Comment: Do you really consider your “simplified” version to be simpler than the original? As chrylis already said, the real simplification is to get rid of double checked locking altogether. Just use `class MySingleton { private static final MySingleton instance = new MySingleton(); public static MySingleton instance() { return instance; }` Whatever advantage you think, double checked locking gave you, it’s simply not true.